# Sustainable Method to Provide Additional Information in Exceptions?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to provide multiple pieces of information for exceptions back to end users.  The obvious solution of extending Exception ends up with text distributed throughput the code, for example

```
throw new MyException("Bad data", "The data you entered is incorrect", "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/baddata");
```

and this quickly becomes unworkable.

I then looked at a catalogue approach but that's too centralized and requires jumping around from one file to another every time an exception is thrown.  I'm now considering a hybrid approach with a static ErrorInfoMap class that contains mappings from a  key to the more detailed information.  Each class then has a static section that contains its own error mappings, so using the class which throws the above exception as an example I'd change it to:

```
throw new MyException("Bad data");
```

and at the bottom of the class there would be something like:

```
static {
  ErrorInfoMap.put("Bad data", new ErrorInfo("The data you entered is incorrect", "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/baddata"));
  // Information for other exceptions thrown by this class goes here
}
```

which allows an exception handler to fetch the additional information if required.  Is this a good way of solving this issue, or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the information into one string? It wouldn't be very pretty, but I'm pretty sure it would work.

Comment: Regardless of how else you manage the data, make sure getMessage returns the concatenated information.

Comment: That would be an uglier version of the first attempt above, so no use to me.  The question is not about the mechanics of exceptions but how and where to put the additional information so that it doesn't clog up the main code but also doesn't live in a totally separate place.

Comment: Have you considered using an enum?

Comment: An enum for the supplementary information?  That would require it to be in a single class so I may as well just use a standard catalogue.  Or did you mean elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "the catalog approach" (could you provide a reference or more detailed description?) but from the information you provided, it's not clear to me how a static ErrorInfoMap avoids the problem of being "too centralized and [requiring] jumping around from one file to another every time an exception is thrown".

To me there are several options, depending on exactly what you need to accomplish:

1. Create a root class, `ExceptionTemplate` that extends `Exception` and does whatever repeatable behavior you'd like all your exceptions to do.  Formatted toString() methods are a good example.  Depending on your exact goals, you might like having your exceptions implement a builder pattern, like so:

   ```
   throw new BadDataException("Supplied data is not valid")
         .expected("a positive integer")
         .referenceUrl("http://www.example.com/moreinfo/baddata");
   ```
2. Avoid [stringly-typed](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html) solutions where an enum or subclass will do.  If you don't need to define new exception types at runtime (and if you do, that should be a red flag that there's something deeper wrong with your design) and have an enum that contains all the necessary information to construct your exceptions:

   ```
   public class EnumException extends Exception {
       private EnumException() {} // prevent objects from being instantiated elsewhere

       public enum Type {
           BAD_DATA("Bad Data","Supplied data is not valid", "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/baddata"),
           MISSING_DATA("Missing Data","Required data not found", "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/missingdata");

           Type(String title, String genericMessage, String url) {
               // Store input
           }

           public EnumException exception() {
               // construct your exception
               return new EnumException();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Which can be called with something like:

   ```
   // note no `new` - the exception is returned by the enum
   throw EnumException.Type.BAD_DATA.exception().expected("a positive integer");
   ```

   This has the advantages of ensuring compile-time type safety, while still giving you the flexibility to define different types of Exceptions in one place.
3. Create lots of exceptions.  I'm still not totally sure what objection you have to just creating a bunch of exceptions.  You're looking for ways to "provide additional information" but claim that "the obvious solution of extending Exception ends up with text distributed throughput the code".  This shouldn't be the case.  Every subclass of Exception should hold all the necessary information except what can only be provided at construction time.  Therefore there should be minimal "text distributed throughout the code" as any boiler-plate / reusable strings should be in the Exception class, and nowhere else.

   ```
   public class DocumentedException extends Exception
   {
       private String title;
       private String genericMessage;
       private String detailedMessage;
       private String url;

       // Generally avoid this long constructor, and define subclasses that only need detailedMessage
       public DocumentedException(String t, String g, String d, String u) {
           super(g + " - " + d); // sets the getMessage() return value to something sane
           title = t;
           genericMessage = g;
           detailedMessage = d;
           url = u;
       }

       public String toString() {
           return title.toUpperCase()+"\n"+
               genericMessage+"\n"+
               detailedMessage+"\n"+
               "More info on this error: "+url+"\n";
       }

       public static class BadData extends DocumentedException {
           public BadData(String details) {
               super("Bad Data", "Supplied data is not valid", details, "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/baddata");
           }
       }

       public static class MissingData extends DocumentedException {
           public MissingData(String details) {
               super("Missing Data", "Required data not found", details, "http://www.example.com/moreinfo/missingdata");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Which you can then call simply with:

   ```
   throw new DocumentedException.BadData("Username cannot contain whitespace");
   ```

   Of course, if you expected to need to warn against username errors regularly, you could create an additional class:

   ```
   public static class BadUsername extends BadData {
       public BadUsername() {
           super("Usernames can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores");
       }
   }
   ```

   The goal, again, is to explicitly define a hierarchy of exceptions that handle all cases you anticipate needing to deal with, such that you avoid repeatedly defining the same strings throughout your application.  I personally like the group-exceptions-into-inner-classes pattern I used above, it lets you be very explicit with your errors without creating hundreds of silly stub java files you need to look through constantly.  I would say that every major package should have an associated exception-holding class that defines all necessary exceptions for that package.

Comment: Thanks this does lay out the options very clearly.  Think I'll end up going with a variant of option 2 (I'm not a fan of large exception trees mainly due to the fact that you end up with lots of classes having the same methods and slightly different data, and to me that feels like it should be multiple instantiations of the same class rather than separate classes).

Comment: I understand the hesitation with creating many classes (especially if they're all stored in separate files) but try not to be concerned with it too much - it's how Java's designed to work.  As long as there's something unique, yet reusable, about an exception you want to throw, the clearest thing to do is create a new type.  With a proper hierarchy, you shouldn't run into too much boilerplate code or duplicated strings, and you'll find the fewest issues utilizing it.  #2's a perfectly viable option, but #3 (with many exceptions in one file) is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your hybrid approach would be to put the error mapping in the exception itself. When `MyException` is initialised with `Bad data` add in the `ErrorInfo` that you've shown, but also provide a range of constructors for `MyException` that allows you to override or supplement the default definition of what `Bad data` means.

Comment: Where you say "add in the ErrorInfo that you've shown" do you mean that the Exception constructor looks the info up, or that the additional information is passed in as an argument to the constructor, or indeed something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could always have "MyException" as the superclass and have the specific types of errors as subtypes of that. In terms of error messages, you can use static constants on the subtypes to store the different types of errors.

E.g

```
Exception    
    -> MyException
      -> BadDataException
      -> InvalidUserException
```

etc.

Would be throw like so:

```
throw new BadDataException(BadDataException.DATA_TOO_LONG);
```

Comment: Trouble with this is that the data returned for each exception is going to be unique.  For example, the data being too long in class A and class B will result in different supplementary information, as will data being too long in two different methods of class A.  So I'd end up with a 1:1 mapping of exception instances to exception classes, and pretty much back to the catalogue approach (in a roundabout way).

Comment: So you never reuse the same exception message in two areas of the application? If so, maybe this approach isn't great. I just dislike the idea of keeping all of the error message strings in the classes themselves as it discourages reuse and makes changing error messages harder later on.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, I'm just struggling to find a better solution.  It might be possible to use an exception tree with each exception containing a number of different templates to generate the information, but I suspect that will become too complex compared to just having individual text strings.

Comment: I guess that more comes down to your specific application and how big it is, how many error messages there will be, etc. - which is something only you know. Having a template system for the classes would actually be fairly simple for most uses (again, not sure of your specific usage). E.g 

new BadDataException(String.format(ErrorCommon.FIELD_TOO_LONG, "someField"));